# The ball for a pong game is stuck outside of the screen

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I made a code for a simple pong game, but the ball keeps glitching outside of the screen. The score increases but the ball are not visible. I was expecting to see the ball go to the center of the screen but instead it is stuck at the bottom. I followed a youtube tutorial for beginners as I haven't coded in a long time. This is the youtube video link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gJnUTX00Z9k

This is the code:

```
import turtle as t
playerAscore=0
playerBscore=0

window=t.Screen()
window.title("Pong-Game")
window.bgcolor("black")
window.setup(width=800,height=600)
window.tracer(0)

leftpaddle=t.Turtle()
leftpaddle.speed(0)
leftpaddle.shape("square")
leftpaddle.color("green")
leftpaddle.shapesize(stretch_wid=5,stretch_len=1)
leftpaddle.penup()
leftpaddle.goto(-350,0)

rightpaddle=t.Turtle()
rightpaddle.speed(0)
rightpaddle.shape("square")
rightpaddle.color("green")
rightpaddle.shapesize(stretch_wid=5,stretch_len=1)
rightpaddle.penup()
rightpaddle.goto(350,0)

ball=t.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape("circle")
ball.color("white")
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0,0)
ballxdirection=0.2
ballydirection=0.2

pen=t.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color("blue")
pen.penup()
pen.goto(0,260)
pen.write("score",align="center",font=("Arial",24,"normal"))


#Movement&Logik

def leftpaddleup():
     y=leftpaddle.ycor()
     y=y+90
     leftpaddle.sety(y)

def leftpaddledown():
     y=leftpaddle.ycor()
     y=y-90
     leftpaddle.sety(y)

def rightpaddleup():
    y=rightpaddle.ycor()
    y=y+90
    rightpaddle.sety(y)

def rightpaddledown():
    y=rightpaddle.ycor()
    y=y-90
    rightpaddle.sety(y)



window.listen()
window.onkeypress(leftpaddleup,"w")
window.onkeypress(leftpaddledown,"s")
window.onkeypress(rightpaddleup,"Up")
window.onkeypress(rightpaddledown,"Down")



while True:
    window.update()
    ball.setx(ball.xcor()+ballxdirection)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() +ballydirection)

    if ball.ycor()>290:
        ball.sety(290)
        ballydirection=ballydirection*-1
    if ball.ycor() > -290:
        ball.sety(-290)
        ballydirection = ballydirection * -1


    if ball.xcor()>390:
        ball.goto(0,0)
        ballxdirection=ballxdirection*-1
        playerAscore=playerAscore+1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Player A: {}       Player B: {}".format(playerAscore,playerBscore),align='center',font=("Arial"))

    if ball.xcor()<-390:
        ball.goto(0,0)
        ballxdirection=ballxdirection*-1
        playerBscore+=1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Player A: {}       Player B: {}".format(playerAscore,playerBscore),align='center',font=("Arial"))


    if (ball.xcor() > 340) and (ball.xcor() < 350) and (ball.ycor() < rightpaddle.ycor() + 40) and (ball.ycor() > rightpaddle.ycor() - 40):
        ball.sety(340)
        ballydirection = ballydirection * -1

    if (ball.xcor() > -340) and (ball.xcor() < -350) and (ball.ycor() < leftpaddle.ycor() + 40) and (ball.ycor() > leftpaddle.ycor() - 40):
        ball.setx(-340)
        ballxdirection = ballxdirection * -1
```

Comment: Something is wrong. For more details show the relevant code as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Check for `ball.xcor` and `-340` is the wrong way, you can also rewrite it nicer: `if -350 < ball.xcor() < -340 and ...`. Maybe some more errors, try rewriting the checks to be cleaner, using variables may help a lot: `ball_inside_paddle_y = leftpaddle.ycor() - 40 < ball.ycor() < leftpaddle.ycor() + 40`, same with `ball_inside_paddle_x` which you then use inside the if check

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code and kept seeing quick flashes of the ball at the bottom of the screen as you probably did.  After reviewing various tests and positioning updates, I found lines where the test condition needed to be corrected from "greater than" to "less than", corrected some range testing, and corrected how some positioning values were derived.  Following is a refactored version of your program where I added some comments noting the corrections made.

```
import turtle as t
playerAscore=0
playerBscore=0

window=t.Screen()
window.title("Pong-Game")
window.bgcolor("black")
window.setup(width=800,height=600)
window.tracer(0)

leftpaddle=t.Turtle()
leftpaddle.speed(0)
leftpaddle.shape("square")
leftpaddle.color("green")
leftpaddle.shapesize(stretch_wid=5,stretch_len=1)
leftpaddle.penup()
leftpaddle.goto(-350,0)

rightpaddle=t.Turtle()
rightpaddle.speed(0)
rightpaddle.shape("square")
rightpaddle.color("green")
rightpaddle.shapesize(stretch_wid=5,stretch_len=1)
rightpaddle.penup()
rightpaddle.goto(350,0)

ball=t.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape("circle")
ball.color("white")
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0,0)
ballxdirection=0.2
ballydirection=0.2

pen=t.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color("blue")
pen.penup()
pen.goto(0,260)
pen.write("score",align="center",font=("Arial",24,"normal"))


#Movement&Logik

def leftpaddleup():
     y=leftpaddle.ycor()
     y=y+90
     leftpaddle.sety(y)

def leftpaddledown():
     y=leftpaddle.ycor()
     y=y-90
     leftpaddle.sety(y)

def rightpaddleup():
    y=rightpaddle.ycor()
    y=y+90
    rightpaddle.sety(y)

def rightpaddledown():
    y=rightpaddle.ycor()
    y=y-90
    rightpaddle.sety(y)



window.listen()
window.onkeypress(leftpaddleup,"w")
window.onkeypress(leftpaddledown,"s")
window.onkeypress(rightpaddleup,"Up")
window.onkeypress(rightpaddledown,"Down")



while True:
    window.update()
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ballxdirection)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ballydirection)

    if ball.ycor()>290:
        ball.sety(290)
        ballydirection = ballydirection * -1
    if ball.ycor() < -290:          # Corrected the comparison operator here
        ball.sety(-290)
        ballydirection = ballydirection * -1


    if ball.xcor()>390:
        ball.goto(390,ball.ycor())  # Corrected the positioning of the ball
        ballxdirection=ballxdirection*-1
        playerAscore=playerAscore+1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Player A: {}       Player B: {}".format(playerAscore,playerBscore),align='center',font=("Arial"))

    if ball.xcor()<-390:
        ball.goto(-390,ball.ycor()) # Corrected the positioning of the ball
        ballxdirection=ballxdirection*-1
        playerBscore+=1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Player A: {}       Player B: {}".format(playerAscore,playerBscore),align='center',font=("Arial"))

    if (ball.xcor() > 340)  and (ball.xcor() < 350)  and (ball.ycor() < rightpaddle.ycor() + 40) and (ball.ycor() > rightpaddle.ycor() - 40):
        ball.setx(340)              # Changed this to setx
        ballydirection = ballydirection * -1
        ballxdirection = ballxdirection * -1    # Added the missing x direction change

    # Corrected the range testing on this
    if (ball.xcor() > -350) and (ball.xcor() < -340) and (ball.ycor() < leftpaddle.ycor() + 40)  and (ball.ycor() > leftpaddle.ycor() - 40):
        ball.setx(-340)
        ballydirection = ballydirection * -1    # Added the missing y direction change
        ballxdirection = ballxdirection * -1
```

With those changes, the ball shows up on the screen and bounces about either off the walls or the paddles.

[image: Pong Game]

There might be some tweaking of the paddle range test for collision as the range and offset was a bit off, but I will leave that for further game refinement.

Try out these tweaks to see if it meets the spirit of your project.